# How can I skip some stacks to just get the backbutton go to the main page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having a problem with the backbutton, so I have a function that is only put on action like 5 pages after the MainPage. Than on that fifth page I want to touch the backButton and go to the MainPage(so 5 pages before that one), is there anyway to throw some code to the back button to do this? How can I do this?

**EDIT1**
"MainPage" is not my root page!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Dennis' answer is correct, and it seems you know how many steps you want to go back, so:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
   // Go back 5 steps when the back button is pushed    
   for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
      Navigation.PopAsync();
   }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, that solution work's for me, but just for curiosity, imagine that i want the same think but i do not know how many pages to go back. Do you have any trick for this situation?

Comment: Great! One way could be to iterate over `Navigation.NavigationStack` to figure out which stack to return back to, similar to Ricardo's suggestion below.

Comment: Nice!! Thank you sir.

Answer (score 3):

Override the `OnBackButtonPressed()` method in the code-behind of your page.

If you want to navigate back to the root page, you can call `Navigation.PopToRootAsync()`:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
    return true;
}
```

If you want to navigate back a single page, just `Navigation.PopAsync()`. If you want to navigate back for example three times, you can call `Navigation.PopAsync()` three times.

Comment: If you think your statement is right, please provide an official document, then I will recognize you. Don't deny others' habits just based on your habits.

Comment: I think its my fault that i use the name "MainPage", but "MainPage" is not my root page, i got other page before that, so  Navigation.PopToRootAsync(), will not work in my case. Got other ideia?

Comment: @Tiagodias You can invoke `Navigation.PopAsync()` multiple times, if you know how far back on the stack you want to go?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it overriding OnBackButtonPressed() but you have to take care because this override just fire when you press physical button then this solution does not work with iOS just android, for iOS you have to create a custom renderer of the navigation page and replace the default back button for a new one and add the necessary action.

other way to get this approach could be on the OnDisappearing() override of the page

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    if (Navigation.NavigationStack.Last() == this)
    {
        Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
    }

    base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

Comment: I think its my fault that i use the name "MainPage", but "MainPage" is not my root page, i got other page before that, so Navigation.PopToRootAsync(), will not work in my case. Got other ideia?

Comment: as we know Navigation has the option to remove pages, then maybe you can get Navigation.NavigationStack and compare  the pages and remove the pages until get the page that you need then when the current page is the same as the page that you need you break this loop. you can compare the pages like this if (navigationPage[0] is YourPage) // your code